# Avoid ant and build automatically instead via eclipse.Is it possible?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, build

I have let's say 4 eclipse projects.
Each references some other until one contains the actual main application.
Meaning that the idea is that each eclipse project is meant to be a library for a main application.
Each eclipse project references some other libraries e.g. spring, commons etc.
My question is the following:
I could write I guess some ant script that copies all the jars to a directory and builds the projects until we get the deliverable that has the classpath configured but is it possible to do something like this automatically via Eclipse?
I tried for example to do export as runnable jar and did not work.
All the referenced jar was not exported.
So is there some automatic way via eclipse or is ant the only option?

**UPDATE:**
I have no problem running the application inside Eclipse.The main eclipse project has references to the other projects it needs. My problem is the delivery of the application.
I.e. some runnable jar that runs standalone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, and you don't have to export any jars.  When you modify the build path in eclipse (Build Path --> Properties), there is a section for referenced projects.  Add the projects you need to reference to the main project and eclipse will treat them as dependencies.